# Laravel- no prob showing directly inserted records, but records saved on app show 'Trying to get property of non-object error'

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I'm building my first project in `laravel`: a family tree. I have a `sql` script to insert my existing records (db is `postgres`), and I'll have forms to add/update records going forward.

I'm seeing a weird bug.  I'm using basic route/model binding for Families (nothing fancy), and I can view an index of all of family records, show info for one, edit info for one, etc.  All of this works fine for the records that I insert with my sql script, and *almost* all of it works fine for records that I new create using the app: the new record appears in the index, and I can edit it (ex: `families/5/edit`), but **when I try to view the info (ex: `families/5`), I get a 'Trying to get property of non-object' error** (see full stack trace at the end of this post).

My first thought was maybe a conflicting route, but I just have this (and all the other routes use different words):

```
Route::resource('families', 'FamilyController');
```

The store method is just:

```
public function store(SaveFamilyRequest $request)
{
    $this->createFamily($request);
    return redirect('families');
}
```

My SaveFamilyRequest has rules to make sure the 5 required fields are there (but new records ARE added to the database so that must have passed in order to reach storing the record).

The show function in the controller just shows the show view with that object:

```
   public function show(Family $family)
    {
        return view ('family.show', compact('family'));
    }
```

The show view just tries to show everything for the {`{$family}}` object

When I view the records in the database everything looks fine (I save fewer fields from my app, but the ones I've skipped are all nullable).

Funny thing is I have the exact same setup for `Person` records, and **for those pages (including the show view) everything works fine for both** imported person records and those that I add on the app.

**What else should I be looking at?**

Thanks in advance for any help/clues!

Stack trace:

```
ErrorException in 6141f213cedd055d619563849681212c line 16:
Trying to get property of non-object
in 6141f213cedd055d619563849681212c line 16
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/home/vagrant/Code/Family-laravel/storage/framework/views/6141f213cedd055d619563849681212c', '16', array('__path' => '/home/vagrant/Code/Family-laravel/storage/framework/views/6141f213cedd055d619563849681212c', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'family' => object(Family)), 'obLevel' => '1', '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'family' => object(Family))) in 6141f213cedd055d619563849681212c line 16
at include('/home/vagrant/Code/Family-laravel/storage/framework/views/6141f213cedd055d619563849681212c') in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/vagrant/Code/Family-laravel/storage/framework/views/6141f213cedd055d619563849681212c', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'family' => object(Family))) in CompilerEngine.php line 58
at CompilerEngine->get('/home/vagrant/Code/Family-laravel/resources/views/family/show.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'family' => object(Family))) in View.php line 135
at View->getContents() in View.php line 106
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 80
at View->render() in Response.php line 51
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 202
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1225
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 113
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(FamilyController), object(Route), object(Request), 'show') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\FamilyController', 'show') in Route.php line 201
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be looking at your view. Maybe you are trying to access a Person on the Family in an incorrect way? ({{ $family->person->name }}) Maybe you've already added people to your families with your SQL script, but you've neglected to do so with your request through Laravel.

Comment: hmmm... I just had a quick look just in case, but it's much more straight forward than that to start: this happens even when the only thing on the view page is  Info: {{$family}}

Also I haven't even added foreign keys yet, so as far as the database is concerned the records only have a couple integers, a few strings, and a bunch of booleans

Comment: Is it possible that you've appended a weird attribute on the Family model? What happens when you try to echo just a single attribute ({{ $family->name }})? What happens when you return the object itself instead of the view? If the app crashes when you return $family; then it's definitely something to do with the visible object properties...

Comment: Yes I think your hunch was right on.

Comment: Yes I think your hunch was right on.  After lots of different changes, the behavior for the original view has changed all together now: now even just showing {{family}} and nothing else DOES WORK for records created in the app and it didn't before.  So I'd say it was a total mystery, however I notice that I also get that very same error when I access the month out of a valid date field (and have confirmed that the record has it), but I can save that one for a rainy day now that my original problem has mysteriously passed.  Thanks for your help/ideas

Answer (score 0):

(after a day of various changes, the same view no longer throws the error from earlier, so i'm closing out the question so others don't waste time on it)